# Iperf bidirectional bandwidth measurement

Tags: linux, bandwidth, iperf, measurement

**Server side:**

```
# iperf -s
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 192.168.24.243 port 5001 connected with 192.168.24.242 port 44809
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.1 sec   113 MBytes  94.1 Mbits/sec
connect failed: Connection refused
```

**Client side:**

```
# iperf -c 192.168.24.243 -r
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.24.243, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  123 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  5] local 192.168.24.242 port 44809 connected with 192.168.24.243 port 5001
Waiting for server threads to complete. Interrupt again to force quit.
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec   113 MBytes  94.8 Mbits/sec
```

Why do I get this error? There's no firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your client is blocking the incoming connection from the server.

The server is reporting "Connection refused".
The client is reporting "Waiting for server threads to complete".

Comment: For an easy test add a (temporary) Netfilter rule to the INPUT-chain: `iptables -t filter -I INPUT -s 192.168.24.243 -p tcp --dport 5001 -j ACCEPT` on host 192.168.24.242.